# SharedPreferences vs. Private File

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, save

In my app, I use a `PreferenceActivity` framework to store persistent data. My intent is to create multiple save files, all of which may be accessed by the `Preference`s, but only one at a time.

When is it better to use a private file generated by `Context.openFileOutput()` and when is it better to use `SharedPreferences`?

**EDIT**
My data exists solely in primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally developers use a preference file that is common to an entire app using `getDefaultSharedPreferences`.

However, Android has a `getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)` method in [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).  You could use this to have multiple preference files, in your case - save files, by using unique names passed into the `name` parameter.

Regarding volatility, you can force the preferences to save by getting an `Editor` via `edit()` and then calling `commit()`.

Make sure to note that the SharedPreferences will indeed be shared based on the `name`:

> Retrieve and hold the contents of the preferences file 'name', returning a SharedPreferences through which you can retrieve and modify its values. Only one instance of the SharedPreferences object is returned to any callers for the same name, meaning they will see each other's edits as soon as they are made.

Comment: So there will be no problem with the security of the data if I use `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: What kind of security are you looking for?  You didn't mention security in your question.

Comment: I'd check out the modes you can open a `SharedPreferences` in. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE

Comment: @Benoir I think that answers what I was looking for. The "security" I was looking for was the access other apps and the system had to it. `SharedPreferences` should accomplish my tasks. Thank you.

Comment: @louielouie : Can the user modify the contents of shared preferences file (and feed some other data into it - not programmatically). Is it stored in the sd card?